# Why does Tomcat's jasper throw a validation error when using a custom param tag?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, tomcat9

I can't include code due to sensitivity reasons, but I have a jsp with 2 taglib imports one is the http://java.sun.com/jstl/core library and one is a custom library. The custom library and the jstl core have a few tags in common one of which is the param tag. The custom param tag extends *org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.ParamTag* and it's parent tag implements the *org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ParamParent* interface, yet it still throws

```
<h3>Validation error messages from TagLibraryValidator for [<custom_lib>] in [/WEB-INF/index.jsp]</h3><p>51: Invalid use of "param" tag outside legitimate parent tag</p>
```

The version of jstl is 1.1.2 and the version of the apache standard libs is 1.1.2. I have tried upgrading to 1.2 as well as adding xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" to the html tag as suggested by the https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37029 bug report

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tags are validated against *.tld. Does your custom tag defined in .tld somewhere?

Comment: @MinhKieu Sorry completely forgot to reply, yes it's defined in a .tld file.

Comment: please paste an example on how you used that tag but the error message above suggests that incorrect defined your tag